# Space just before minipage

Tags: spacing, indentation, minipage, framed

This is my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength{\FrameSep}{3pt}
\begin{document}
   \noindent{}The king\\
   \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
      is dead,
      \begin{framed}
         Long live
      \end{framed}
      the king
   \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: current]

This is the intended output:

[image: intended]

The spacing between "The king" and "is dead" should be the same as that between "is dead" and "Long live"(Ignore the left margins, couldn't take the screenshot properly).

Of course I could replace

```
\noindent{}The king\
```

by

```
\noindent{}The king\\[4mm]
```

or something, but I want something more elegant. What is the best way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about using this instead --  The king \par\vspace{0.5cm}

Comment: Can it be done without specifying "0.5cm"?

Comment: \bigskip will also do the trick.

Comment: Add a blank line before the `minipage` (then adjust the indenting).

Comment: @karlkoeller -- adding a blank line is the same as adding `\par` after the double backslash.  you *do* get the extra vertical space, but you also get the message `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)`, which isn't a good tradeoff.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using `\baselineskip` to make the vertical space.  Remember `\noindent` when starting new paragraphs here.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed}
\setlength{\FrameSep}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent
The king

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
  is dead,
  \begin{framed}
    Long live
  \end{framed}
  the king
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```